# How to print an array of ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created a array of `ArrayList` but now I want to access its elements and sort them and print them, please help me to find out a way

```
  ArrayList<Integer>[] lists = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[20] ;
  for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
    lists[i]=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lists[i].add(i+i*2);
    lists[i].add(i+i*3);
    lists[i].add(i+i*4);
    lists[i].add(i+i*5);
  }  
   System.out.println(lists);
```

output:-

```
[Ljava.util.ArrayList;@15db9742
```

Comment: Arrays.toString(lists)

Comment: So the problem is how to print an array in a readable form?

Comment: (let's duplicate this for future readers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-) to print the content of your array as next:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lists));
```

> `Arrays.toString(Object[]):`
>   Returns a string representation of the contents 
>   of the specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, they 
>   are converted to strings by the `Object.toString()` method inherited from 
>   `Object`, which describes their identities rather than their contents.

Using `Arrays.toString(Object[])` to print the content of your array is enough in your case as an `ArrayList` is a subclass of `AbstractCollection` which overrides `toString()` to give a `String` representation of the collection in square brackets using a comma as value separator and here values are `Integer`s.

Comment: thanks it works but what if i want to modify an ArrayList at ith index of an array ? how to access?

Comment: `lists[n]` will return the n + 1 th element of your array

Comment: Oh damn !! , bye the way thanks